# Rails link_to w/ path AND url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, link-to

**How do I set a path *and* :path_only => false for Rails' link_to method?**

Our site has a lot of rails-made hyperlinks looking like this:

`<% link_to "anchor text", "/path/" %>` which yields `<a href="/path/">anchor text</a>`

I have the assignment to replace relative urls in our links with absolute urls.  Naturally, it occurs to me to set `:only_path => false`, but I don't know how to do that when I'm already supplying a path instead of url_options.

Yes, I could specify other url_options (controller, action, id), but for the scale on which I'm working, it's far simpler to use a path than to look up ids, actions, and controllers.

Using Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest replacing your hard-coded paths with the named route helper functions.  If instead of `"/path/"` the previous programmer had used `path_path` you would be able to replace `_path` with `_url` and be done with it.  If you find a way to force all your links to be absolute instead of relative, the next person who needs to change something will be in the same boat as you are now.  Even if there is a relatively high overhead for replacing paths, it is the right way to go.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer or provide an example?  I'm not versed in named route helper functions.

Comment: This guide is for rails 3 but the idea of creating and using named routes exists in rails 2.3.x as well (You don't specify which version you're using).  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Basically, there are methods generated by the routing system (run `rake routes` to see a list of the ones for your app).  These will look like `user`, `edit_user`, `new_user`, etc.  You can append `_path` or `_url` to any of them to get a relative path or absolute url in any view or controller.